# Difference between connecting throug Jenkins SSH plugin and normal ssh

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

I have a remote server.
If I use `ssh` to connect with the server as the Jenkins user it works perfectly

```
ssh jenkins@remoteserver.com
```

The `jenkins` user is allowed to change to user `jboss` WITHOUT being asked for password:

```
sudo su jboss
```

This works perfectly, no need for entering a password. Everything as expected.

If I make a Jenkins build, connecting to the remote server through a SSH plugin, the connection works fine. I can also run a testscript, it works also!

But if I make the `sudo su jboss` through Jenkins on my remote server, it's not working.
Jenkins is not throwing any error, there is just the spinning circle
[image: spinning circle]
It's never stopping, only if I cancel the job.

Anyone got an idea, what's the difference between running `ssh` in Jenkins and conncecting through a plugin?
Is the connection lost, when changing the username? (looks like it)

Answer (score 1):

The [SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin) and the `ssh` command provide two completely **different implementations of the SSH protocol**:

- Your `ssh` command will probably run the [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) client
- The SSH plugin uses the SSH protocol implementation provided by [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

I'm not into `JSch`, but I'd suspect there's a either a problem in the way the plugin configures `JSch` terminal handling, or there's a problem related to terminal handling with `JSch`. Either may break the behaviour of `sudo`:

`sudo` is somewhat sensitive to terminal/tty settings; see e.g. [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83389/sudo-hangs-when-run-on-remote-host-over-ssh-in-a-script-without-tty-t), which also contains a few hints which may help to work around the issue.

Comment: Hm ok. Is there any Jenkins SSH plugin which allows to `sudo su` ?

Comment: There is only one SSH plugin. Maybe you can get it working with the tips provided in the link I gave (they involve changing the ssh config files). If not, then you could file a bug against the SSH plugin and/or try to fix it yourself.

Comment: I manged to be able to switch my user without entering a password (as mentioned above). My question was, if changing the user crashes the ssh , not the sudo, maybe that was not clear from my question

Comment: I think that you're stuck in the `sudo` call. And (presumably) that's caused by the tty/terminal handling in the SSH plugin. `ssh` is not crashing anywhere.